# Append a div to content returned in jQuery post function

Tags: jquery

I hope someone can help solve the issue I'm having as follows.

I make a call to a php file using jQuery post() and the returned result is html, I now wish to append a div to the bottom of a container on the page. Heres some code

js

```
   var serializedData = $("#jobListing").serialize();
        var posting = jQuery.post("/?action=jobs-status-changes", serializedData);
        posting.done(function(data){
            jQuery(data).find('#content1').append('<div>Please close this window to reload the page.</div>');
            //alert(data);
            jQuery.colorbox({
                html:   data + '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {jQuery(".menu-top").hide()});</script>',
                width: "40%",
                maxHeight: "66%",
                scrolling: "true",
                transition: "fade",
                onClosed: function(){
                    location.reload(true);
                }
            });
        });
```

I read somewhere that the html returned from jQuery post is an object and can be used as above

`(jQuery(data).find('#content1').append('<div>Please close this window to reload the page.</div>');)`

Am I missing something here? I realise I could parse the string but would like a jQuery solution if possible.

thanks

Comment: have you checked console logs on browser?

Comment: Hi Bhushan, the html in console log does not show the expected string 
        
        `<div id="content1">            
        <h1>Updating job(s) status</h1><p>Jobs 59129, 59126 updated</p></div>`

Comment: I think you need to store `data` jquery object and then modify it and pass html of object to colorbox. Please check my answer posted

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

HTML: Add below empty div in your html code

```
<div id="dummy" style="display:none"></div>
```

JQuery: push `data` in dummy div and find required content1 to append html. Use dummy div html in colorbox

```
var serializedData = $("#jobListing").serialize();
        var posting = jQuery.post("/?action=jobs-status-changes", serializedData);
        posting.done(function(data){
            var $dummy = $("#dummy");
            $dummy.html(data);
            $dummy.find('#content1').append('<div>Please close this window to reload the page.</div>');
            //alert(data);
            jQuery.colorbox({
                html:   $dummy.html() + '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {jQuery(".menu-top").hide()});</script>',
                width: "40%",
                maxHeight: "66%",
                scrolling: "true",
                transition: "fade",
                onClosed: function(){
                    location.reload(true);
                }
            });
            $dummy.html('');
        });
```

Comment: `var posting = jQuery.post("/?action=jobs-status-changes", serializedData);
            posting.done(function(data){
                var $data = jQuery(data);
                $data.find('#content1').append('<div>Please close this window to reload the page.</div>');
                alert($data.html());
        ` returned undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#jobListing").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    selectedJobEditor();
    var serializedData = $("#jobListing").serialize();
    var posting = jQuery.post("/?action=jobs-status-changes", serializedData);
    posting.done(function(data){
        var dota = jQuery(data).find('#content1').append('<div>Please close this window to reload the page.</div>');
        alert(dota);
        jQuery.colorbox({
            html:   dota.html() + '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {jQuery(".menu-top").hide()});</script>',
            width: "40%",
            maxHeight: "66%",
            scrolling: "true",
            transition: "fade",
            onClosed: function(){
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

thanks to the suggestion by Bhushan Kawadkar I was able to resolve this with corrected code above